# How can I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk using git pull instead of uploading the whole repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Right now I'm using `eb deploy` to deploy an application to Elastic Beanstalk. However the upload process is relatively slow. I was wondering if it's possible to get Elastic Beanstalk to run git pull so that it's downloading the latest set of diffs instead of uploading the entire repository each time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
You could however set up a separate environment that does a git pull every so often and deploys to beanstalk if there are changes. 
The upload should be fairly quick instance to instance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to setup a clean Continuous Integration process using something like CodeShip or some other SaaS Service. Usually you can do this for free and it provides nice Continuous Delivery deployments straight to Elastic Beanstalk and a lot of other services.

I have written about it recently [here](http://compositecode.com/2015/04/08/__2-got-our-kanban-lets-start-a-basic-loopback-api/) and [here](http://compositecode.com/2015/06/05/__3-going-the-full-mile-continuous-delivery/) to specifically do what you're aiming to accomplish.